# How do I read Core Data descriptions?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm having trouble debugging core data. I have two objects

```
<MyClass: 0x7f9eab6cc7e0> (entity: MyClass; id: 0xd000000000300000 <x-coredata://24C40E7B-ECD2-48C5-89A6-03F85727EC5A/MyClass/p12> ; data: {})
```

and

```
<MyClass: 0x7f9eab672190> (entity: MyClass; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://24C40E7B-ECD2-48C5-89A6-03F85727EC5A/MyClass/p1> ; data: {})
```

The two objects have different pointers but should point to the the same Core Data Object. Both have the same `<x-coredata://24C40E7B-ECD2-48C5-89A6-03F85727EC5A/DBUser/>` but differ in the p12 and p1. What does these lines mean? To the system they are two different object when they should be the same one.

How can I understand what Core Data description string is telling me?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are in the wrong direction trying to debug your issue based on this format. What exactly is the issue? Are these 2 objects in the same context or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little more, I found these. The NSManagedObject description is conformed like this.

> x-coredata://[Store UUID]/[Entity Name]/[Primary Key]

Where primary key is related to the entry in the data base. The problem that I had was fetching a wrong object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are persisting data using SQLite, then p1 and p12 relate directly to the row of data in the table, which is identical to saying the primary key of that record.

If you learn how to access your SQLite store using Terminal, you will be able to retrieve the entire table of data for this entity and see that the two records you retrieved were in fact on lines 1 and 12.